# How to build tile url as per loris standard?

Tags: openseadragon

I am using openseadragon for displaying tile source. The tile source server is expecting the parameters like following

jpg/0,0,500,800/105,/0/default.jpg

How to build this url from openseadragon's getTileUrl(level, x, y) callback?

I get only the level,x,y. My question is how to build it inside getTileUrl() method?

Comment: Is your Loris server serving IIIF? If so, you should just be able to give it the IIIF URL like so: http://openseadragon.github.io/examples/tilesource-iiif/

Comment: Yes my Loris server is serving IIIF. I am able to give the IIIF url in @id 


tileSources:   [{
      "@context": "http://iiif.io/api/image/2/context.json",
      "@id": "https://libimages1.princeton.edu/loris/pudl0001%2F4609321%2Fs42%2F00000001.jp2",
      "height": 7200,
      "width": 5233,
      "profile": [ "http://iiif.io/api/image/2/level2.json" ],
      "protocol": "http://iiif.io/api/image",
      "tiles": [{
        "scaleFactors": [ 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 ],
        "width": 1024
      }]
    },

Comment: In this case openseadragon appends the request params like region,x,y,width,height

Like  "https://mylorisserver/pudl0001/4609321/s42/00000001.jpg"

What I need is to add few more parameters after the request param

like below

"https://mylorisserver/pudl0001/4609321/s42/00000001.jpg?signature=somesignature"

Comment: Perhaps your most straightforward solution would be to monkey patch the IIIFTileSource's getTileUrl to add your own extra params.